Non-convergence of Cauchy product of a given series
Given the following series,
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}
$$
our goal is to show that the Cauchy product of the series with itself doesn't converge.
The Cauchy product of two series is defined as follows:
Let two series be given by:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n, \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n.
$$
The $\textit{Cauchy product}$ of these two series is defined as:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n,
$$
where the coefficient $c_n$ in the product series is given by the convolution of the coefficients $(a_k)$ and $(b_{n-k})$, that is:
$$
\quad c_n = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}, \, \forall n \geq 0
$$
Here's my attempt on the problem:
Taking the original series (and following the notation given in the definition of the Cauchy product),
$a_n=b_n=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+1}} \, \forall n \geq 0$, and so, the Cauchy product of the series with itself will be the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n$, whose coefficients will be given by:
\begin{align*}
    c_n &= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k} \\
        &= \sum_{k=0}^n a_k a_{n-k} \\
        &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^k}{\sqrt{k+1}} \cdot \frac{(-1)^{n-k}}{\sqrt{n-k+1}} \\
        &= \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{(k+1) \cdot (n-(k-1))}} \\
        &= (-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(k+1) - (k^2-1)}}.
\end{align*}
One way to prove that the Cauachy product doesn't converge, would be to prove that
$c_n \nrightarrow 0$ (as $n\rightarrow \infty$). To make it easier, we could study the limit convergence of
$$
|c_n|=\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(k+1) - (k^2-1)}},
$$
since $c_n \rightarrow 0 \iff |c_n| \rightarrow 0$.
I wrote $|c_n|$ as:
$$
|c_n|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(k+1) - (k^2-1)}}
$$
Taking into account that $\forall k$ such that $1 \leq k \leq n: 
\sqrt{n(k+1) - (k^2-1)} \leq \sqrt{n(k+1)}$, we have that:
$$
|c_n| \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(k+1)}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}
$$
We just have to see that the term on the right side doesn't tend to $0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This is the most delicate part.
We can't just substitute and try to compute the limit directly, since
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow 0$ and
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=\infty$, and we get an indetermination that cannot be solved easily. Instead, I tried to resort to the asymptotic behaviour of the sum to try to solve this. As $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ are all positive and decrease strictly as $k$ increases, when $n$ is big, the sum should behave (asymptotically) as the integral:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} \thicksim \int_{1}^{n} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \, dk = 2\sqrt{n} - 2
$$
(I used $\sqrt{k}$ instead of $\sqrt{k+1}$ since I'm just interested in the behaviour when the terms are infinitely big, and so the constant doesn't affect.)
Taking this into account, as we're computing the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ and the sum behaves asymptotically as $2\sqrt{n} - 2$ or, equivalently, $2\sqrt{n}$, then
$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ should converge around $2$, or less specifically, it shouldn't converge to $0$. Then, given that
$|c_n| \geq 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$, and since the term on the right side doesn't tend to $0$, we get that $|c_n| \nrightarrow 0$, and so,
$c_n \nrightarrow 0$, and we get the desired result.
I have doubts about the last part of the proof. I do understand the asymptotic behaviour of sums (in a mid/basic level), but I'm not really sure whether the reasoning behind the computation of the limit is correct. I'd say it's true that as $n$ approaches infinity, the sum should behave as $2\sqrt{n}$, but I don't know if you can directly use this fact to prove that the limit of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ isn't $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. I would be really grateful if someone could clarify for me the reason why this proof may be correct, or where it fails to follow a well-enough formal process.
PD: In case anyone is curious, the motive behind this exercise would be to see that there are convergent series whose Cauchy products with themselves don't converge, in an attempt to see that some series may not have to fulfill the Mertens's theorem conditions (see Question about Proof of Merten's theorem (Cauchy-Product formula) for reference). In this case, one can easily see that the series converges by using Dirichlet's test (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test), but it doesn't converge absolutally, so Mertens's theorem could not be applied. I think the question also serves a good way to better understand how to interpret and deal with the asymptotic behaviour of sums, specially through the study of limits.

One thing to note: did you realize that the sum you're looking at is just a series, not a power series? There are no powers of $z$.

Ah, yes. It's just that I took this problem from one of my textbooks on complex analysis, where we're always considering power series and sequences of complex coefficients. I'd say it doesn't affect the result but it's a good point to make for people not to be confused about it. Thanks!

Are you sure your result is true? It seems that Abels radial convergence theorem infers it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem

Well, unless the question in my textbook is wrongly written, then it should be true.

Isn't it Mertens's theorem that assures that if any of two series is absolutely convergent, then their Cauchy product converges? Two convergent series do not have to have a convergent Cauchy product.

Oh yes there was a subtlety I did not grasp, the power series corresponding to $c_n$ converges in one to to product $(\sum a_n)(\sum b_n)$but we are not granted that the result is the limit of the sequence $\sum_{k\leq n} c_n$

We would need that (its the partial reciprocal of Abel's theorem) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy–Littlewood_Tauberian_theorem and it is not verified here

Let $d_n=(n+1)^{-1/2}.$ Then $$d_kd_{n-k}\ge d_n^2={1\over n+1}$$ We have $$\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k}=(-1)^n \sum_{k=0}^nd_kd_{n-k}$$ Thus $$  \left |\sum_{k=0}^na_ka_{n-k}\right | =\sum_{k=0}^nd_kd_{n-k}\ge (n+1){1\over n+1}=1$$ Hence the $n$th term of the Cauchy product does not tend to $0.$

One can use that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k+1}{n}}} \geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{k}{n}+1}}.$$
Setting $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ for $x\in [0,1]$ (notice it's a continuous function), one finds that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\geq \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^nf(\frac kn),$$
the RHS converging by Riemann sums to $\int_0^1f(x)dx = 2(\sqrt2 - 1) > 0$. Thus $\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}$ does not converge to $0$ as $n\to \infty$.
To answer your question about the validity of your own proof, I feel like you didn't justify properly why the sum behaves asymptotically as the integral, especially why we have an equivalence. It is easy to prove that they have the same nature for a decreasing function (i.e both divergent or both convergent), but you would have to prove yourself that they are equivalent when they both diverge (the proof shouldn't be too complicated if you follow the steps for the proof of the integral test of convergence).

Starting from what you wrote$$|c_n| \geq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n(k+1)}}=
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}\tag 1$$
Using harmonic numbers
$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k+1}}=H_{n+1}^{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}-1$$
Cosndering that $n$ is large, the rhs of $(1)$ write
$$2+\frac{\zeta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{n}}+\frac 3{2n}-\frac 1{2 n^{3/2}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Using limits
$$\huge\color{blue}{\sqrt2 \leq |c_n|\lt 2}$$
